# Elegantly exploding flat array to a nested associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a return from an API call that delivers a category tree as a flat array with parent/child relationships spelled out with repeated strings.  A small sample:

```
                [0] => Architecture & Street Scenes
                [1] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail
                [2] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork
                [3] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork/Balconies
                [4] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork/Fences
                [5] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Courtyards
                [6] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Exteriors & Street Scenes
                [7] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Interiors
                [8] => Architecture & Street Scenes/Street Lamps
                [9] => Art & Culture
                [10] => Art & Culture/Dance
```

Is there an elegant way using PHP to get from there to eliminating repetition and expressing the relationships by having child arrays?

```
                    [0] => Architecture & Street Scenes
                      [0] => Architectural Detail
                        [0] => Cast or Wrought Ironwork
                        [1] => Cast or Wrought Ironwork
                            [0] => Balconies
                            [1] => Fences
                      [1] => Courtyards
                      [2] => Exteriors & Street Scenes
                      [3] => Interiors
                      [4] => Street Lamps
                    [1] => Art & Culture
                        [0] => Dance
```

Comment: Is that the end array format you must have, or could you go for a different format that is nested?

Comment: @crush I could deal with another format as long as parent-child relationships were expressed in the structure

Comment: Can you guarantee that they are in alphabetical order?

Comment: @crush Yes; the API returns them in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that you'd use each token as a key to create a hash table.

```
<?php
$api = array(
    "Architecture & Street Scenes",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork/Balconies",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Architectural Detail/Cast or Wrought Ironwork/Fences",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Courtyards",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Exteriors & Street Scenes",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Interiors",
    "Architecture & Street Scenes/Street Lamps",
    "Art & Culture",
    "Art & Culture/Dance",
);

$end = array();

foreach ($api as $v) {
    $tokens = explode('/', $v);
    $parent = &$end;

    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        if (!array_key_exists($token, $parent)) {
            $parent[$token] = array();
        }

        $parent = &$parent[$token];
    }
}

print_r($end);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [Architecture & Street Scenes] => Array
        (
            [Architectural Detail] => Array
                (
                    [Cast or Wrought Ironwork] => Array
                        (
                            [Balconies] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [Fences] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Courtyards] => Array
                (
                )

            [Exteriors & Street Scenes] => Array
                (
                )

            [Interiors] => Array
                (
                )

            [Street Lamps] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [Art & Culture] => Array
        (
            [Dance] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So then, when you are iterating over them, you could do:

```
foreach ($end as $k => $v) {
    echo $k; //Here is your top level element.
    //You'd then iterate through it's children which are in $v.
}
```

Comment: Before your edit it seemed to work perfectly; after the } else {
            $parent[$token] = array();
            $parent = &$parent[$token];
        } was removed the $end array is empty

Comment: Okay I will fix it when I get home. I am on my commute now

Comment: I tested this code now that I am at home, and it seems to work. Maybe you have a copy/paste error?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Whatever is did incorrectly before I don't know.  You are correct; it works just fine.  Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate your time and help very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it, here's a recursive option that'll achieve the same thing regardless of the order of input data.

```
$output = array();

foreach($api_data as $line){
    process_children($line, $output);
}

function process_children($line, &$output){
    $split = explode('/', $line, 2);

    if(!isset($output[$split[0]]))
        $output[$split[0]] = array();

    if(isset($split[1]))
        process_children($split[1], $output[$split[0]]);
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: My answer also achieve the results regardless of the order

Comment: Works great!  Thank you!  But why explode on newline?  I changed to foreach($api_data as $line){ and it does the trick.  Much obliged!

Comment: Sorry - that was from my test code where I had the data completely flat.

Comment: The reason that I asked about the order of the elements was because in order to produce the array in the format originally posted one would have to iterate the entire array to search for existing tokens. Thus, if it is pre-sorted alphabetically, the time to search could be greatly reduced. However, the hash map simplifies this approach by being able to store the name as the key instead of the value.